# Can I look up email address from a PGP/GPG fingerprint?

Tags: email, pgp

If I know a PGP fingerprint, can I query a keyserver to find out what email address(es) it is associated with?

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can, just take that fingerprint remove spaces and add `0x` at the beginning.

Then make a search query:

```
https://keyserver.cns.vt.edu/pks/lookup?search=0x...
```